# How to configure so that IE in WinXP always stays on top

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

One of our project machine(WinXP) is installed with a software(HMI) that monitors a bunch of devices. The machine is setup such as that whenever the machine boots up, it'll automatically starts the HMI software. You don't get to see any WinXp interface at all.No Start button, no task bar.... nothing. Quiting the HMI software will shutdown the machine. In addition, the HMI software blocks certain keys combination such as Alt-Tab, Alt-F4  etc etc except Ctrl-Alt-Dlt.

Whenever a user starts IE from the HMI software(a launcher), the IE appears in front of the HMI software GUI. The issue is that, whenever the user clicks at the HMI GUI, the IE will hide behind the HMI GUI and there is no way to call it back. Thus, user will have to launch another IE from the HMI to use it again.

**Is there a way, to force IE to always be in front although something behind the IE is clicked?
Please advise.**

I can access the normal WinXp interface by logging in the HMI software as admin. Then closing the HMI will return me to the WinXP interface.

Answer (score 2):

See the free [Eusing Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm):

> Auto Window Manager automatically
>   manages any window you specify. For
>   instance, some web browsers open up in
>   a non-maximized window. Using Auto
>   Window Manager, you can set those
>   windows to automatically maximize
>   (minimize, normal, minimize to tray,
>   stay on top) every time they opened.
>   It works with almost any program,
>   including web browsers, Notepad, etc.
>   Auto Window Manager stays running in
>   the system tray, so it stays out of
>   your way while it works.

Comment: Wow! +1 for that great find :)

Comment: thanks for the link... I just tried out Auto Window Manager... It does exactly what I'm looking for...forces IE to stay on top during next launch or system reboot.. but the Registration Window appears everytime the system starts up unless I register/donate for it... still a great piece of software nonetheless..

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[ProcessMonitor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/processpriority/files/)** to achieve this. After installing it, right click on Internet Explorer in the taskbar and choose Always on top. This change is **not** permanent, though. It's only until the window is closed.

Comment: thanks for the link... just tried it also... works great but it only applies for the specific IE window... I'm looking for something that force IE to stay on top forever(next startup)... Thanks though

Comment: That really is tough, I'll give you that :). I'll edit my answer to say it's not permanent.

Answer (score 0):

[**PowerMenu**](http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/) adds items in the System Menu of all applications, including an "Always on top" option.

Comment: thanks for the link... just tried it... works great but it only applies for the specific IE window... I'm looking for something that force IE to stay on top forever(next startup)

Answer (score 0):

you can run Internet Explorer in 'kiosk mode'

just add the the switch **-k** to your shortcut.

Keyboard Shortcuts for Kiosk Mode:

> CTRL+A           Select all
>   (editing)
>
> CTRL+B           Organize favorites
>
> CTRL+C           Copy (editing)
>
> CTRL+F           Find (on current
>   page)
>
> CTRL+H           View History
>   folder
>
> CTRL+L           Open Location
>   dialog box
>
> CTRL+N           New window (opens
>   in non-Kiosk mode)
>
> CTRL+O           Open Location
>   dialog box (same as CTRL+L)
>
> CTRL+P           Print
>
> CTRL+R           Refresh
>
> CTRL+S           Save
>
> CTRL+V           Paste (editing)
>
> CTRL+W           Close (same as
>   ALT+F4)
>
> CTRL+X           Cut (editing)
>
> ALT+F4           Close
>
> ALT+LEFT ARROW   Back
>
> ALT+RIGHT ARROW  Forward
>
> ESC              Stop
>
> F5               Refresh

to close IE use Alt + F4

Source: [MSKB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780)

Comment: thanks for the tip... though not what i'm looking for at the moment... i need to IE to operate normally except that it just stays on top all the time.... anyway, thanks again... i learned something new today :)