# How to make Internet Explorer 9 always on top?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, always-on-top

I've looked at and tried solutions to [similar questions](https://superuser.com/questions/39553/how-to-configure-so-that-ie-in-winxp-always-stays-on-top) but doesn't seem to work with my combination of **IE9** on **Windows 7**. It just seems IE9 ignores any attempt to change its always-on-top property.

Any solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case there wouldn't be a clean built-in solution,
I suggest you this AutoHotKey program: [Always-on-top](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/keep-window-always-on-top/5213/)

- launch the utility
- select a window
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to stick that window in the front.

The program code is a one-liner  `^SPACE::  Winset, Alwaysontop, , A`